# SQL query to extract data from a varray

Tags: sql, oracle

I've used a varray to store my a maximum of two mobile numbers in my customer table:

```
create or replace type mobile_array as varray(2) of
varchar2(11);
```

Im trying to produce a query which filters mobile numbers beginning with '0770'. Since i've used a varray i'm not sure how i approach the query to take the varray into consideration as it contains the data i want to query. I have attempted it, however I dont seem to be making much progress.

```
select c.custname.firstname,c.custmobile.mobile_array
from customer c
where c.custmobile.mobile_array like '0770%';
```

Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a temporal table or a view.

> > create table #tmp (id int identity not null, mobile varchar(11), customerid int)

And then

> > select c.custname.firstname,tmp.mobile
> >     from customer c
> >     inner join #tmp tmp on c.customerid=tmp.customerid
> >     where tmp.mobile like '0770%';

Comment: I'm not familiar with temporal tables or views, is there a way to produce the query keeping the varray? Or am i over-complicating it?

Comment: Yes there is, but have you considered to add the fields to the table instead using varray?.

Try this
>>SELECT t1.custname, t2.column_value FROM custmobile t1, TABLE(t1.custmobile) t2 WHERE t2.custmobile like '0770%';

[Source](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/VARRAY)

Comment: Its a project which requires me to use as many object-relational features as possible, so im trying to retain the varray and produce a query with the current table design as i dont want to de-construct it at present.

Comment: @user3487430 were you able to query the varray? How did you do?